# MongoDB conditional aggregation with unwind

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have db collection like:

```
{
  "_id" : "af5c00e4-d3a8-419d-8793-c0cf328802ec",
    "collaborators" : [
        {
            "_id" : "9bd2eee8-bf6c-4c6f-bab7-d2d175aed807",
            "origin" : [
                {
                    "originId" : "123"
                }
            ],
            "firstName" : "Parveen",
            "lastName" : "Vendor",
            "email" : "pk@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "234324-bf6c-4c6f-bab7-d2d175aed807",
            "origin" : [
                {
                    "originId" : "1234"
                }
            ],
            "firstName" : "Parveen123",
            "lastName" : "34",
            "email" : "abc@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "orders" : [
        {
            "totalAmount" : 10,
            "collaborators" : [
                {
                    "origin" : [
                        {
                            "originId" : "123",
                        }
                    ],
                    "type" : "Supplier"
                },
                {
                    "origin" : [
                        {
                            "originId" : "1233",
                        }
                    ],
                    "type" : "Supplier"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Want to replace data in  **orders (array) collaborators(array)** with

**collaborators(array) ** data if matches originId  of both

**Expected output**

```
{
  "_id" : "af5c00e4-d3a8-419d-8793-c0cf328802ec",
    "collaborators" : [
        {
            "_id" : "9bd2eee8-bf6c-4c6f-bab7-d2d175aed807",
            "origin" : [
                {
                    "originId" : "123"
                }
            ],
            "firstName" : "Parveen",
            "lastName" : "Vendor",
            "email" : "pk@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "234324-bf6c-4c6f-bab7-d2d175aed807",
            "origin" : [
                {
                    "originId" : "1234"
                }
            ],
            "firstName" : "Parveen123",
            "lastName" : "34",
            "email" : "abc@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "orders" : [
        {
            "totalAmount" : 10,
            "collaborators" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "9bd2eee8-bf6c-4c6f-bab7-d2d175aed807",
                    "origin" : [
                        {
                            "originId" : "123"
                        }
                    ],
                    "firstName" : "Parveen",
                    "lastName" : "Vendor",
                    "email" : "pk@gmail.com"
                },
                {
                    "origin" : [
                        {
                            "originId" : "1233",
                        }
                    ],
                    "type" : "Supplier"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

One collection record can have multiple collaborators , same as order can have multiple collaborators.
Need to replace only where originId matches

Comment: Why are `collaborators.origin` and `orders.collaborators.origin` are arrays? Will they always include only one item?

Comment: @nimrodserok yes, only one.
But due to some third party dependency its in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is:

1. Use `$map`, `$mergeObjects` and `$filter` to add a `new` key to each item of `orders.collaborators` with the matching item from `collaborators` if exists.
2. choose the `new` key if it contains data or the `original` key, if not.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {
      ordersCollaborators: {
        $map: {
          input: {$first: "$orders.collaborators"},
          in: {$mergeObjects: [
              {original: "$$this"},
              {new: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$collaborators",
                    as: "i",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        {$first: "$$i.origin.originId"},
                        {$first: "$$this.origin.originId"}
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$set: {
      orders: [
        {totalAmount: {$first: "$orders.totalAmount"},
          collaborators: {
            $map: {
              input: "$ordersCollaborators",
              in: {
                $cond: [
                  {$eq: [{$size: "$$this.new"}, 0]},
                  "$$this.original",
                  "$$this.new"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      ordersCollaborators: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HjAjrgBW1ED)